# How to mass rename files with ill-formed numbering?

Tags: rename

I've got bunch of files with ill-formed numbering:

```
prefix-#.ext       | for files with number 1-9
prefix-##.ext      | for files with number 10-99
prefix-###.ext     | for files with number 100-999
```

Due to further processing I need all of their names to be in format: `prefix-###.ext`. Is there any easy way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Debian, Ubuntu and derivatives, you can use the [`rename` Perl script](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/prename.1.html):

```
rename 's/(?<=-)([0-9]+)/sprintf "%03d", $1/e' prefix-*.ext
```

Some systems may have this command installed as `prename` or `perl-rename`. Note that this is not the `rename` utility from the util-linux suite which does not provide an easy way to do this.

In zsh, you can use [`zmv`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv) to rename and the `l` [parameter expansion flag](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags) to pad with zeroes.

```
autoload -U zmv
zmv '(prefix-)(*)(.ext)' '$1${(l:3::0:)2}$3'
```

You can also do this with a plain shell loop. Shells don't have nice string manipulation constructs; one way to pad with zeroes is to add 1000 and strip off the leading `1`.

```
for x in prefix-*.ext; do
  n=${x%.ext}; n=${x##*-}; n=$((n+1000))
  mv "$x" "${x%-*.ext}${n#1}${x##*-}"
done
```

Another way is to call the `printf` utility.

```
for x in prefix-*.ext; do
  n=${x%.ext}; n=${x##*-}
  mv "$x" "${x%-*.ext}$(printf %03d "$n")${x##*-}"
done
```

Comment: The first example is beautiful one-liner. However, on ArchLinux it's called `perl-rename`, not just `rename` or `prename`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this (untested)

```
for n in *.ext; do
    echo mv "$n" \
      "prefix-$(printf %03d "$(basename ${n#prefix-} .ext)").ext"
done
```

Remove the `echo` to do the actual renaming.

Note: you have to be in the directory where the files are for this method to work; dealing with pathnames that contain a directory part is more complicated.

Comment: Yep, it works. If've found `perl-rename`, but I don't know how to make `###` numbers from variable length numbers.

Comment: you don't, instead you find numbers that are too short. and add zeroes,

Answer (score 1):

```
for file in prefix-*.ext
do
    num=`echo $file | sed 's/prefix-\(.*\).ext/\1/'`
    [ $num -lt 100 ] && mv $file prefix-`printf "%03d" ${num}`.ext
done
```