# Adding 0 to single digit number in filenames

Tags: bash, shell-script

These are my sample files

```
user@linux:~$ ls -l | cut -d ' ' -f 10-

ch 10 - file.txt
ch 2 - file.txt
ch 3 - file.txt
ch 4a - file.txt
ch 5 - file.txt
user@linux:~$
```

I would like to add `0` to any single digit (including `4a`) so the final output would be like this.

```
user@linux:~$ ls -l | cut -d ' ' -f 10-

ch 10 - file.txt
ch 02 - file.txt
ch 03 - file.txt
ch 04a - file.txt
ch 05 - file.txt
user@linux:~$
```

Is this possible using built-in tools in Linux?

Comment: What do you consider to be "built-in tools in Linux"? does this help [How to mass rename files with ill-formed numbering?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189928/how-to-mass-rename-files-with-ill-formed-numbering)

Answer (score 1):

The pattern

```
'ch '[1-9][!0-9]*'- file.txt'
```

would match all filenames that needs changing (out of the ones that you show), i.e. any filename that starts with `ch` , followed by a digit between 1 and 9, followed by something that is not a digit. After that, we allow for any characters whatsoever, and the names must end with `- file.txt`.

We can loop over these files with

```
for name in 'ch '[1-9][!0-9]*'- file.txt'; do
    ...
done
```

The objective is now to insert a `0` after the `ch`  bit.  This can be done by stripping the `ch`  substring off, and replacing it with `ch 0`:

```
for name in 'ch '[1-9][!0-9]*'- file.txt'; do
    newname='ch 0'${name#ch }
done
```

The `${name#ch }` parameter substitution would expand to `2 - file.txt` if `$name` contained `ch 2 - file.txt` (it would remove the prefix `ch` ).

After this, you could just rename the file:

```
for name in 'ch '[1-9][!0-9]*'- file.txt'; do
    newname='ch 0'${name#ch }

    printf 'would rename "%s" into "%s"\n' "$name" "$newname"
    # mv -i "$name" "$newname"
done
```

Remove the `#` on the line with the commented out `mv` command after running the loop once to see that it does the correct thing.

The loop above, given the filenames that you show, would output

```
would rename "ch 2 - file.txt" into "ch 02 - file.txt"
would rename "ch 3 - file.txt" into "ch 03 - file.txt"
would rename "ch 4a - file.txt" into "ch 04a - file.txt"
would rename "ch 5 - file.txt" into "ch 05 - file.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

With Lary Wall's `rename`/`prename` (`rename` in Debian/Ubuntu, `prename` in RedHat/Fedora):

```
rename -n 's/^ch (\d) /ch 0$1 /' *
```

`-n` is for dry runs, remove (or replace with `-v') for actual execution.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for.

What is need to be done basically are as follows:

1, check if the digit is single or double-digit. If it is single digit and the value less than or equal to 9 then, rename the file. Which should be as simple as doing:

```
(( someDigit <= 9 )) && [[ ${#someDigit'slength} -lt 2 ]]
```

2, since there would be some files with letters so, we can store them as:

```
digit=$( echo $file | cut -d '-' -f1 | grep ch | awk '{print $2}' );
```

3, then filter the digit so that we can compare it for first option. Add more filters which you may feel would be necessary in `tr -d` option as follows:

```
digitOnly=$( echo $digit | tr -d [a-Z] );
```

4, then run a loop in your directory where you intend to rename the files. Implementing all of this would look as follows:

```
for file in *file.txt; do
  digit=$( echo $file | cut -d '-' -f1 | grep ch | awk '{print $2}' );
  digitOnly=$( echo $digit | tr -d [a-Z] );
  if (( digitOnly <= 9 )) && [[ ${#digitOnly} -lt 2 ]]; then
    # mv "${file}" "ch 0${digit} - file.txt"
    echo "'${file}' is renamed to 'ch 0${digit} - file.txt'";
  fi
done
```

Remove the # from mv, after you are satisfied before real execution.
With your example:

```
touch 'ch 10 - file.txt' 'ch 2 - file.txt' 'ch 3 - file.txt' 'ch 4a - file.txt' 'ch 5 - file.txt'
```

Then, executing the script or copying pasting the above `script` in `bash` will give you the following output:

```
'ch 2 - file.txt' is renamed to 'ch 02 - file.txt'
'ch 3 - file.txt' is renamed to 'ch 03 - file.txt'
'ch 4a - file.txt' is renamed to 'ch 04a - file.txt'
'ch 5 - file.txt' is renamed to 'ch 05 - file.txt'
```

Obviously, you can even make it more generic, by including it in a function then take input such as file pattern search and so on, but your question does not demand that. So, I believe, the current answer would handle the situation stated in the question quite well.

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv # best in .zshrc
zmv -n '*[0-9]*' '${f//(#m)<->/${(l:2::0:)MATCH}}'
```

(remove `-n` (dry-run) if happy).

Would `l`eft-pad all numbers to width 2.

Beware it also *truncates* numbers to width 2 (would change `1234-2.txt` into `34-02.txt`).

Not sure what you mean by *builtin*, especially in relation to *Linux* which is just a kernel. `autoload` is a zsh built-in, but note that the `zmv` autoloadable function invokes the `mv` utility which is not a builtin by default (but can be made so with `zmodload zsh/files`).