# Rename specific files by inserting zeros to filename

Tags: linux, ubuntu, zsh

#### Question

How do I rename files from

```bsh
p1.py p2.py ... p99.py
```

to

```bsh
p001.py p002.py ... p099.py
```

In zsh running on Ubuntu

##### Why

I don't like the way files appear as shown below (p6.py is between p59.py and p60.py)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189928/how-to-mass-rename-files-with-ill-formed-numbering

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mass rename files with ill-formed numbering?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189928/how-to-mass-rename-files-with-ill-formed-numbering)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `zmv` and the `l`eft padding [parameter expansion flag](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags):

```
autoload -Uz zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmv -n 'p(<0-999>).py' 'p${(l[3][0])1}.py'
```

Remove the `-n` (dry-run) to actually do it.